# How to Prevent Accidental Touch pad Activation Triggering Privacy & Security Window on MacBook Pro 16

Tags: macbook-pro, security, trackpad, privacy

I'm facing a rather frustrating issue with my MacBook Pro 16. While typing, I often accidentally touch the Touch pad, which triggers the Privacy & Security window to pop up. This is becoming quite annoying, and I'm looking for a way to stop this from happening.

Here's what occurs:
[image]

I'm not sure what causes this specific window to open, but I'd like to either disable this feature or find an alternative solution that prevents the Touch pad from opening this window unintentionally.

Additionally, I'm including the configuration details of my MacBook for reference:
MacBook Pro 16-inch, 2019

- Processor: 2.6 GHz 6-Core Intel Core i7
- Graphics: AMD Radeon Pro 5300M 4 GB
- Memory: 16 GB 2667 MHz DDR4
- macOS: Sonoma 14.1

Any advice or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Voting to close. You've left out essential details: What are you pressing on the Touch Bar? Are you using BTT? Screenshots of Touch Bar helpful.

Comment: @JBallin, i made an error, not touch bar, but touch pad, i don't know what i press on it, this is the point for me to understand why does it work like this, it happens accidently while im typing

Comment: I've just tried to deliberately trigger trackpad 'input' with my palms while typing, and been unable to; apart from actually pressing down and clicking. It's very weird that 'random' trackpad input would consistently open the Privacy panel. Do you get any alert or dialog? Do you have any third-party utilities installed, that might trigger ANY activity? Also check Settings for your trackpad gestures configuration. (E.g. what happens when you two-finger drag, etc.) Are you able to deliberately open the Privacy panel with a specific gesture?

Comment: Hmm Touch Pad? Do you mean Trackpad?

Comment: First thing to check is your trackpad settings, like ben said. You can set up shortcuts there like hot corners etc. that you may be triggering by accident. You could also check accessibility settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the core problem thanks to @benwiggy comment, he led me the right way, so if it is possible I would give a bounty to him.

After upgrading to macOS Sonoma in my Touch Bar, was added the button **Extensions Settings** which I can't get rid of, first I thought it only looked bad, but now I understand that it was the problem, I actually clicked on it with my left hand accidentally, and since I was used to the Touch Bar not bothering me before (in OS Ventura) and it was empty, I couldn't figure out what the problem was.

PS to mods, I want to share the bounty with @benwiggy, is it possible? (he guided me to solve the problem)

[image: Photo of the Touch Bar on a Mac laptop with the button 'Extensions Settings' on the left side]

Comment: I'm OK for points. So it was the touch bar, not trackpad. Glad you got it sorted.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to share a bounty, so just ask benwiggy to post an answer and award them the bounty.